# Rails issue with "route matching"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting the following error when loading this URL: localhost:3000/groups/5/post/new

> No route matches [GET] "/groups/5/post/new"

I am trying to create a new "post" for a specific group. Here is my Post controllers "new" action:

```
  def new
    @group = Group.find(params[:group_id])
    @post = Post.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end
```

I have my routes orginized as so:

```
resources :groups do
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Does anyone see anything that may be causing this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
localhost:3000/groups/5/post/new
```

Should be

```
localhost:3000/groups/5/posts/new
```

Comment: whoops... Beginners mistake haha

Answer (score 0):

Using that nested resource, shouldn't the path be?: /groups/5/posts/new (note the plural posts)